# Authority formating for MSAL - and GetAccountAsync returning no data

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to get a token from AzureB2C tenant, and can't get past the first stage, I suspect maybe my Authority is not formed correctly.
But all the resources I find say different things. I don't know what is supposed to be part of it and what is not.

```
string ClientId = "adde324e....8b";

        string Authority = "https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/a6f2ee42...7b4384a/v2.0";

        PublicClientApplication application = new PublicClientApplication(ClientId, Authority);

        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await application.GetAccountsAsync();

        AuthenticationResult result = null;

        result = await application.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(new string[] { "user_impersonation" }, accounts.FirstOrDefault());
```

I am getting no accounts at all, and yes, I only run this code once I have logged in.

I tried using removing the tfp and the v2.0 as well as swapping the tenant id for "common". also tried using login.onmicrosoft.com instead the b2clogin.com. but nothing works. Still getting no data.

Answer (score 0):

The authority should be in this format:

```
 public static string AzureADB2CHostname = "login.microsoftonline.com"; // or {Your-Tenant-Name}.b2clogin.com
 public static string PolicySignUpSignIn = "b2c_1_susi";
 public static string AuthorityBase = $"https://{AzureADB2CHostname}/tfp/{TenantId}/";
 public static string Authority = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicySignUpSignIn}";
```

Here is documentation on using [MSAL and B2C](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AAD-B2C-specificities#use-msalnet-to-sign-in-users-with-social-identities)
Each B2C policy is its own OIDC endpoint, which means each policy will have it's own refresh token in the cache. Each time you target a new policy, you will want to include it as part of the authority.

For example:

```
public static string PolicyEditProfile = "b2c_1_edit_profile";
public static string PolicyResetPassword = "b2c_1_reset";

public static string AuthorityEditProfile = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicyEditProfile}";
public static string AuthorityPasswordReset = $"{AuthorityBase}{PolicyResetPassword}";
```

Here's a [B2C Desktop App](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-desktop/blob/master/active-directory-b2c-wpf/App.xaml.cs#L11) as a example.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this did not help me. It must be something else. I am still getting no accounts. I have seen this desktop app before, unfortunately I cannot use that code as .net core does not have the AcquireTokenAsync method. only the AcquireTokenSilentAsync one.

Comment: @zawisza Did you see this [net core sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/AzureAdB2COptions.cs#L28) 
Authority is created, same as above, but with `/v2.0` at the end. I think you're just missing the policy in your authority.

Comment: @zawisza what error are you getting? Are you including the policy?

Comment: yes, I am including the policy. There is no error as such, the GetAccountsAsync method is returning null. The weird thing is that if I make the authority wrong on purpose I get the same result. So I don't know if the GetAccountsAsync is returning null because the authority is wrong or not.

Comment: @zawisza I have updated the [net core sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp) do you want to try it out? The scope was wrong, so an access token was not returning.

Comment: Thanks Jenny, I see your sample works really well. I don't use openid in my project so am trying to integrate what you had into mine. Not yet working. But hopefully I will work it out.

Comment: I am still stuck in the same place. Still no accounts returned. Yet it works when I use your sample. I have also found that some other people had a similar problem when they upgraded to MSAL2.7 from 2.5. Using this sample:
https://github.com/mattruma/ADB2CWebAppWebApi
I downloaded it and also managed to replicate it too. It works but stops when I upgrade to 2.7. And yet your code on 2.7 works, even though I cannot really see any significant differences. I am stumped.

Comment: @zawisza Do you get an access token and IdToken back?

Comment: when I run your own sample, it works. I can connect to my own API on my own tenant. But when copying the code to my app, it does not work. I get no accounts after : var accounts = await cca.GetAccountsAsync();

Comment: Can you share your code? You can email a link to it.

Comment: I have emailed you.